# Python move and overwrite folder without delete destination folder content

Tags: python, copy, directory, move, overwrite

I need  move folder and it's content from dir1 to dir2. Dir2 contains files which I do not want to delete . How to achieve this?

Comment: The classic comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Just found solution - distutils.dir_util.copy_tree

Answer (score 3):

Use the [shutil package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).

It's a package that allows you to do anything with files. The only caveat, which you should expect, is that if you move a file from dir1 to dir2, and there is a file with the same name in dir2, that file will be deleted.

It's possible that you could do a check to see if there exists a file in dir2 before you do the move. Then, you could either abort the move or change the name of file in dir2 before you do the move. Either way works.

This is the code

```
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system('mv /path/to/d1 /path/to/d2')
```

Works if you have a *nix shell and want the entire folder moved over.

```
import os
os.rename('d1', 'd2/d1')
```

Otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
import distutils.core
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree
```

This solved my problem.